# Не обновляется значение ForeignKey

Tags: php, phalcon, mysql

Здравствуйте! Уже третий день бьюсь. Проект на Phalcon.

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
Users (id, login, pass, role_id)
Roles (id, name, description)
```

У каждого пользователя есть роль (Связь role_id с таблицей Roles по ForeignKey).
В модели Roles прописано:

```
$this->belongsTo('role_id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Roles', 'id', array(
    'alias' => 'Role'
));
```

При обновлении пользователя возникает проблема: всегда ставится одна и та же роль, которая идет первая в таблице ролей, независимо от значения, которое я устанавливаю.

Пробовал несколькими способами:

```
$user->role_id = 4; // не работает
$user->Role->id = 4; // (ВНИМАНИЕ КОСТЫЛЬ!) работает, потому что обновление ID у роли запускает изменение всех строк пользователей, у которых та же самая роль.
```

Записи с ID 2 и 4 есть в таблице Roles.

В самом Phalcon известен баг, что нельзя назначить null в поле, на которое установлен ForeignKey ([раз](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1296), [два](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2039), [три](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1804/how-to-save-foreign-key-with-null-value-), [четыре](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2033/null-foreign-key-on-mysql-orm)), но у меня же не null, а реальное значение.

Версия Phalcon: 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаком с Phalcon, но, насколько понял из доков, нужно не присваивать атрибуту fk новое значение, а присваивать модели новую связанную модель (`$user->Role = $newRole`).

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Тогда в ту роль, которую мы назначаем, копируется текущая роль. В результате получается 2 копии одной роли.

Comment: На официальном форуме фалкона ответили так же. Сейчас заработало! Спасибо!:)
http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3210/not-update-foreignkey-value